# Edit view still shows after rescuing from Pundit::NotAuthorizedError and redirecting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, pundit, responders

I have a pretty standard setup: `Identity::Member` are users, and each `Project::Project` is owned by a member. I use `Devise` and `Pundit` together for authentication and authorization.

Here's my code for `Project::ProjectPolicy`

```
class Project::ProjectPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  attr_reader :member, :project

  def initialize(member, project)
    @member = member
    @project = project
  end

  ...

  def update?
    member == project.member
  end

  def edit?
    update?
  end

  ...

end
```

And here's my `edit` action:

```
  # GET /projects/1/edit
  def edit
    authorize @project_project
    respond_with @project_project
  end
```

Lastly, the rescue setup in `ApplicationController`

```
rescue_from Pundit::NotAuthorizedError, with: :member_not_authorized

def member_not_authorized
  respond_with current_member, status: :unauthorized, location: -> { root_path }
end
```

But... for some reason, clicking on edit will still bring you to the edit view, although all changes are blocked and users are redirected to the root_path just as I instructed for update and destroy actions. Why?

Comment: Have you tried **not** using `respond_with` in your `member_not_authorized` call ? I am wondering if that's defaulting back to the `edit.html.erb` when the underlying `render` is called.

Comment: What is `@project_project`? How is it defined?